# Nightwatchjs folder structure

Tags: continuous-integration, nightwatch.js

What's the simplest folder structure I can use with Nightwatchjs? It will be used locally and for continuous integration. Currently I can't even get the demo to work. I have six errors:

```
module.js:469:15
module.js:417:25
bootstrap_node.js:604.10
bootstrap_node.js:394:7
bootstrap_node.js:149:9
bootstrap_node.js:509:3.
```

I realize this is a beginner question. I've been using Telerik and TestComplete for a few years and now we want to do CI properly so Selenium is the way to go. I'm comfortable with javascript but kind of bad at file path stuff.

Comment: please post the config file (Nightwatch.js file)

Answer (score 0):

> What's the simplest folder structure I can use with Nightwatchjs?

## The simplest NightwatchJS folder structure is:

- To have 2 files (a configuration file and a file which contain you tests):

  - `nightwatch.json`
  - `app.js` (you can rename it as you want)

## Example

1) **nightwatch.json**

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "app.js"
    ],
    "live_output": false,
    "tests_output": "test/tests_output/",
    "detailed_output": true,
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false,
        "host": "hub.browserstack.com",
        "port": 80
    },
    "test_workers": {
        "enabled": false,
        "workers": "auto"
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "chrome": {
            "selenium_port": 80,
            "selenium_host": "hub.browserstack.com",
            "silent": true,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "os": "Windows",
                "os_version": "10",
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "resolution": "1024x768",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "browserstack.video": "true",
                "browserstack.debug": "true",
                "browserstack.user": "<yourUsername>",
                "browserstack.key": "<yourPassword>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) **app.js**

```
module.exports = {
    'Does-stackoverflow-works': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
            .waitForElementPresent('body', 2000, "Display latest Stackoverflow questions")
            .end()
    }
};
```

## Run

```
$> nightwatch --env chrome
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I redid my install and the issue went away. The problem had to do with the order of the install. I could have fixed the errors by changed the path for a bunch of files. A correct install kept me from having to do so and I didn't lose any of my work.